# Displays image from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

Displays.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("toko_blog");
$sid = session_id();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bukti_transfer");
?>
<h1 class="Judul">Laporan</h1>
<table id="datatables" class="TableCart">
<thead>
<tr><th>No</th>
    <th>Nama File</th>
    <th>Gambar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
$no = 1;
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo"<tr><td>$no</td>";
    echo"<td>$r[file_name]</td>";
    echo'<td><img src="gambar.php?id='.$gambar['id'].'" width="150" /></td></tr>';
 if($no % 4 == 0){
echo '</tr><tr>';
 }
$no++;
}
?> 
</tbody></table>
```

gambar.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("toko_blog");
$idFile = $_GET['id'];

$dataGambar = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from bukti_transfer where id='$idFile'"));
$filename = $dataGambar['file_name'];
$mime_type = $dataGambar['mime_type'];
$filedata = $dataGambar['file_data'];
header("content-disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
header("content-type: $mime_type");
header("content-length: ".strlen($filedata));
echo ($filedata);
?>
```

I want to display an image from a MySQL database. The image was saved in the  database but when it is displayed, the image is corrupted.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `gambar.php` is the file that displays the image so that code we would need to see, not this

Comment: <?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("toko_blog");
$idFile = $_GET['id'];

$dataGambar = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from bukti_transfer where id='$idFile'"));
$filename = $dataGambar['file_name'];
$mime_type = $dataGambar['mime_type'];
$filedata = $dataGambar['file_data'];
header("content-disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
header("content-type: $mime_type");
header("content-length: ".strlen($filedata));
echo ($filedata);
?>

Comment: Please edit your question and post it there